# Search filter applied through "link_to"

Tags: ruby-on-rails

So i have a search filter working perfectly in my index view. The code in the controller is as follows

```
def index
    @tutor = Tutor.where(:admin => false)
    @tutor_array = []

@tutor_array << @tutor.fees_search(params[:fees_search]) if params[:fees_search].present?
@tutor_array << @tutor.subject_search(params[:subject_search]) if params[:subject_search].present?
@tutor_array << @tutor.lssubject_search(params[:lssubject_search]) if params[:lssubject_search].present?
@tutor_array << @tutor.ussubject_search(params[:ussubject_search]) if params[:ussubject_search].present?
@tutor_array << @tutor.jcsubject_search(params[:jcsubject_search]) if params[:jcsubject_search].present?

@tutor_array.each do |tutor|
  ids = @tutor.merge(tutor).map(&:id)
  @tutor = Tutor.where(id: ids)
end
@tutor = @tutor.sort_by { |tutor| tutor.rating.rating }.reverse
@tutor = @tutor.paginate(:page => params[:page], :per_page => 2)
```

end

And in my view the form that passes in the search filters for me is

```
<form class='form-inline'>
    <%= form_tag(tutors_path, method: :get) do %>
    <div class='row', id='filter-form'>
      <div class='form-group'>
        <%= label_tag 'subject_search', 'Primary Subject' %>
        <% subject_array = Subject.all.map { |subject| [subject.name] } %>
        <%= select_tag 'subject_search', options_for_select(subject_array, :selected => params[:subject_search]), :include_blank => true, class:'form-control' %>
        <%= label_tag 'lssubject_search', 'Lower Sec Subject' %>
        <% lssubject_array = Lssubject.all.map { |lssubject| [lssubject.name] } %>
        <%= select_tag 'lssubject_search', options_for_select(lssubject_array, :selected => params[:lssubject_search]), :include_blank => true, class:'form-control' %>
        <%= label_tag 'ussubject_search', 'Upper Sec Subject' %>
        <% ussubject_array = Ussubject.all.map { |ussubject| [ussubject.name] } %>
        <%= select_tag 'ussubject_search', options_for_select(ussubject_array, :selected => params[:ussubject_search]), :include_blank => true, class:'form-control' %>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class='row', id='filter-form2'>
      <div class='form-group'>
        <%= label_tag 'jcsubject_search', 'JC Subject' %>
        <% jcsubject_array = Jcsubject.all.map { |jcsubject| [jcsubject.name] } %>
        <%= select_tag 'jcsubject_search', options_for_select(jcsubject_array, :selected => params[:jcsubject_search]), :include_blank => true, class:'form-control' %>
        <%= label_tag 'fees_search', 'Max Fees' %>
        <%= select_tag 'fees_search', options_for_select((10..150).step(10), :selected => params[:fees_search]), :include_blank => true, class:'form-control' %>
        <%= submit_tag 'Filter', class: 'btn btn-primary btn-xs' %>
      </div>
    </div>
    <% end %>
    <div id='filter-reset'>
      <%= link_to 'Reset Filters', tutors_path, class: 'btn btn-primary btn-xs' %>
    </div>
  </form>
```

And when a filter is passed in an example or the URL attained is as follows

```
/tutors?utf8=✓&subject_search=Science&lssubject_search=&ussubject_search=&jcsubject_search=&fees_search=&commit=Filter
```

What i would like to ask is, how do i pass in the filters through a button?

[image]

So if i were to click on "Math" or "English" its equivalent to passing in the filter through the form? I understand that it'll most likely be `link_to tutors_path(???)` but what should go into the parenthesis to pass the correct filters in?

Answer (score 0):

I tried `<%= link_to subs.name, tutors_path(:subject_search => subs.name %>` and it seems like it works. To provide some context here's the view and how `subs.name` comes about.

```
<% tutor.subjects.each do |subs| %>
  <span class='badge'id='tutor-listing-badge'>
    <%= link_to subs.name, tutors_path(:subject_search => subs.name) %>
  </span>
<% end %>
```